# Postgresql Enum comparison not working on one specific type

Tags: postgresql, enums, operators

Can't seem to compare two (of the same) *enum types*. If I run the command...

```sql
SELECT 'test'::core.mytype = 'test'::core.mytype;
```

it gives the following error...

```sql
ERROR:  42725: operator is not unique: core.mytype = core.mytype
LINE 1: SELECT 'test'::core.mytype = 'test'::core.mytype;
                                   ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
LOCATION:  op_error, parse_oper.c:718
```

If I try this on another Enum type I have, it works perfectly fine, just seems to be this particular type.   Not only that, but I'm sure I've been using the comparison for a few weeks now in another function.

Is there something I'm missing, or may have possibly removed by accident?

Comment: Btw, using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: Runs for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2fc468573c8446c87902bd87231835d5 Maybe you could try to create a fiddle that shows the behaviour?

Comment: wish I could, but only seems to be this one particular enum type.   I've even tried restarting the service just to be sure.

Comment: Also, there's no custom operators on it nor is it any different from all the other enum types that work.

Comment: can you show the type definition and the corresponding table definitions that are relevant for the query

Comment: unfortunately not, since the project is under an NDA, so it's limited to share.  I tried a dbFiddle, but unfortunately schemas can't be created, so I can only test it on the public schema, which works.

Comment: Have destroyed and created the schema and still having the same issue.  what's interesting is that all other enum comparisons work.  It's just this particular type

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that this was a result of a `CAST` function, which I still do not understand why.

There was an [implicit] CAST from the given type to `JSON`/`JSONb`.  I am assuming that PostgreSQL was converting to `JSONB`/`JSONB` and comparing that and failing (which is understandable), but the error output mentioned nothing about `JSON`.

Anyway, after having removed the cast (or at least making it `ON ASSIGNMENT`), it seems to now work.

Crazy...but good to know.